# ruby bitwise product

Tags: ruby, performance

I've got an assignment where I have had to write a function, which takes two integers and returns it's bitwise product. Bitwise product equals to bitwise sum (`&`) of all numbers between these two.

For example: bitwise product of `251` and `253` is:

```
irb(main):164:0> 251 & 252
=> 248
irb(main):165:0> 252 & 253
=> 252
irb(main):166:0> 248 & 252
=> 248 # this a bitwise & of these two between 251 & 253
```

My function:

```
def solution(m,n)
  (m..n).to_a.inject{|sum, x| sum &= x}
end
```

Test:

```
irb(main):160:0> (251..253).to_a.inject{|sum, x| sum &= x}
=> 248 #same result
```

The program's evaluation:

> correctness 100%
> performance 0%

Can anyone, please explain what is with performance of this function? Thanks in advance!

## EDIT

Since *performance* is undefined here, can you provide an analysis of the function for, for example, really big inputs and criticise/suggest better/more efficient solution?

p.s. thx for comments guys, i will follow the recommendations!

Comment: what are you using to evaluate your code?

Comment: @user3536548 it is just a result of the test, so I don't know how it was evaluated

Comment: I'd recommend as a first step understanding the performance of your code. Look into the `Benchmark` gem. Then you can see when your changes improve performance, until you start registering on your black-box test.

Comment: Then how are we supposed to know what performance is? The test works out a performance metric but we can't know what performance means without knowing how it works it out and we can't know that without knowing what test runs the code. Still, my guess is the test has a preset code function already in it or values for a pre-written function and it measures against that. 100% is exactly the same speed and it goes down the slower the function runs untill its so slow its not really good enough (i.e. 0% is like 4 seconds slower and therefore not acceptable according to the test or however its set).

Comment: @user3536548 yea, I think your suggestion is really close to reality, so I just assumed there are not so many factors of effectiveness when it comes to simple operations on numbers, and gaps would be visible to experienced SO guys at first sight. But I can be wrong

Comment: You can call `inject` directly on a Range, so no need to create the array with `to_a`: try `(m..n).inject :&`, maybe constructing the large arrays is causing the performance problem.

Comment: or implement the function in C using rubyinline gem :D, also shouldn't you be telling inject what your injecting? I,e, `.inject({})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on my comment, you can experiment using Benchmark:

```
def solution(m,n)
  (m..n).to_a.inject{|sum, x| sum &= x}
end

def solution2(m,n)
  (m..n).reduce(:&)
end

n = 50000
Benchmark.bm(7) do |b|
  b.report("orig:") { n.times do; solution(128,253); end }
  b.report("new: ") { n.times do; solution2(128,253); end }
end
```

Here's what I get:

```
              user     system      total        real
orig:     1.560000   0.000000   1.560000 (  1.557156)
new:      0.640000   0.000000   0.640000 (  0.634063)
```

You appear not to have any choice but to do the above, experiment to find a faster algorithm, and run the test until you register on the performance meter.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious performance problem here is a conversion to array (`to_a`), it's not necassary. You can call `reduce` and `inject` (appear to be the same) an any `Enumerable`, `Range` includes it as well. `Enumerable` is basically everything that can produce a finite (it's arguable, but mostly true) sequence of elements. `Range` seems to fit, if treated as a set of integers.

In order to iterate over an array with elements in this range, you first create an array and fill it with elements (by iterating over `Range`). Then you iterate on the resulting array applying your operations. So you create an array for the purpose of iterating on it, fill it, use it, toss it away. And it takes quite a memory allocation to do that if the range is large.

The next one, which is not critical, but reduces the amount of code that you have, requires some knowledge on the internal implementation of operators in Ruby. When you write `a&b` you are actually doing `a.&(b)`: calling a `&` method on a number.

The `sum` you get in the block is not really some sort of `accumulator`, you don't actually need to assign anything there, `sum` is an intermediate value, the result of adding a new element should actually be a return value. Since an assignment returns the assigned value, it works even this way. Proof of that is this:

```
(251..253).inject{|sum, x| sum & x } # => 248, as expected
```

...and it turns out, this block is trivial: take one value, call a method on it with another value. Since `inject` takes a pair of values on each iteration, you can just give it a method name and let it handle the situation. Method names in Ruby are typically referenced with symbols like this:

```
(251..253).inject(:&) # => 248, as expected
```

All right, about twice as less code, less actions done and less objects made, nevertheless same result.

```
def solution(m,n)
  (m..n).inject(:&)
end
```

We haven't looked closely at `inject`. Can you beat `inject` performance-wise? It's unlikely, it's a C method and is used here exactly for its purpose, you can look it up easily using gems `pry` and `pry-doc` (install, launch `pry` and type in `show-source Range#inject`):

```
[11] pry(main)> show-source Range#inject

From: enum.c (C Method):
Owner: Enumerable
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 34

...a bunch of C code here
```

Comment: thank a lot for decent explanations, man! I would go with first solution about Benchmark, but I am really appreciated!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko We actually have the same solutions in the end `:P` I'm just explaining the performance issues behind yours. @MarkThomas has actually explained how to measure this, which will allow you do find out "is it any good" by yourself.